# e4view still throws ClassCastException and expects IViewPart

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

I read [Contribute e4 Views into the IDE](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2FwhatsNew%2Fplatform_isv_whatsnew.html) and am trying to incorporate this into my application.

My extension definition:

```
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <e4view
            class="com.mycompany.myplugin.views.MyView"
            id="com.mycompany.myplugin.views.my"
            name="My view"
            restorable="true">
      </e4view>
   </extension>
```

My view is as simple as it can get:

```
public class MyView {

    @PostConstruct
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {}

    @Focus
    public void setFocus() {}
}
```

However, I still get a `ClassCastException` that my `MyView` can't be cast to `IViewPart`. I am using Neon.2 (4.6.2). Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Show us a stack trace of the exception

Comment: I got it to work by cleaning and re-generating the runtime workspace.